# Sharepoint Workspace - copy text file VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

I need to copy a text file that is saved locally to a Sharepoint workspace.

I tried doing a simple copy

```
My.Computer.Filesystem.CopyFile("c:\test.txt", "c:\users\USER_NAME\Workspaces\SP_NAME\Documents\USER_NAME\test.txt")
```

and it works, but it doesn't put it in the workspace properly. Any tips/pointers on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Check if the paths exists with code, when check if app is running with administrator or not.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can't

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Accessing-workspace-data-from-your-file-system-in-SharePoint-Workspace-2010-1365ebf2-a45e-45cc-bfc4-bdae528b32f4#bm3

damn, this stinks. gotta find a new work around